# Calculate how high a cell value is compared to a formula with a variable

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to know how I can 'compare' a cell's value based on a formula with a variable. Very specifically, I have the expression `100 * 25^n` and my cell that is being compared to it, `E2`. If my cell is greater than `100 * 25^0` but less than `100 * 25^1`, I would like this formula to display `2^1`. If the cell is greater than `100 * 25^1` but less than `100 * 25^2`, I would like the formula to display `2^2`. I would like the formula to continue 'comparing' until it reaches the highest value of n my cell goes to then display 2^n. Of course, I could write this as multiple IF functions, like so:

`=IF(E2 >= 100 * 25^0, IF(E2 >= 100 * 25^1, 4, 2), 1)`

However, this would be very messy, would take a long time to copy paste and wouldn't go on infinitely, so it isn't a very good choice for my problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly what you want is 2 raised to the LOG base 25 of the number in E2 divided by 100, rounded down to the nearest integer. If that is correct, try the following formula:

```
=POWER(2,ROUNDDOWN(LOG((E2/100),25),0)+1)
```

However for some values of `E2` below 100, this will still give a result of 2 so you'll need an `IF`

```
=IF(E2<100, 1, POWER(2,ROUNDDOWN(LOG((E2/100),25),0)+1))
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for; when E2 is below 100, I should get 1, when E2 is between 100 and 2499 I should get 2, when E2 is between 2500 and 62499 I should get 4, when E2 is between 62500 and 1562499 I should get 8 (When E2 is 100*25^n I should get 2^(n+1)).

Comment: See my edited answer